# 8-character limit on old email addresses

Tags: email, unix, character, limits

I have been trying to research this, but I can't seem to find a definite answer.  Back in the early 1990s when email was rather new for the mass consumers the email addresses often had 8 character name @ something.xxx.   Why was the 8 character limit chosen?  I know that early email servers were running on UNIX.  Are there any correlation between the limit and the server running on UNIX?

Comment: It is a *"history of computers"* question rather than a *"programming"* question, admittedly, but the answer is wrapped up in the programming limits of the time. To get on my soapbox, I find many programmers to be surprisingly ignorant of our shared history. I say let it be because it is instructive about programming in a limited environment.

Comment: Thank you for allowing this in the programming section.  I do find it important to understand whether the limitation was technical to programming or something else.  I wrote several programs back in the old DOS days and I always had to worry about the 8.3 file name length. I'm trying to understand whether the 8 char limit in old email was something similar or it had something to do with the system being on UNIX.  Another thing I was curious about is whether DOS was modeled after UNIX.  No on would obviously claim that, but I have some suspicion that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back then a variety of systems had an eight character limits for a number of things like file names, passwords, and userids.  Some systems which allowed longer names required that they be unique in the first eight characters.  Mail was usually delivered to a spool file based on the userid.  Users preferred having the same userid accross systems, so following the least common denominator princpal, userids where usually eight characters or less.

Email ran on a variety of platforms, although until SMTP interconnectivity was limited.

This followed through to email addresses which were usually userid @ somesever.  Even today, this is common.  Aliases allow users to provide longer addresss like First.Last@example.com which migtht be delivered to lastfi.

Comment: Thank you.  This knowledge is very helpful especially trying to understand whether the limitation had anything to do with memory allocation, encoding/decoding of string information.  I also found that newer UNIX o/s no longer has the 8 character limitation, but if the 8-char limit was a tradition rather than a technical limitation then it makes sense why it was chosen back then and even now.

Comment: On some systems it was a limitation, and others a tradition or used for compatibility with systems where it was a limitation. I used to verify the name fields on systems with my name.  Many couldn't handle Thorsteinson in the last name field as it was too long.  I prefer to log on as bill or billthor rather than Bill.Thorsteinson or some such long name.

Answer (score 3):

Early unixes allowed for longer user names BUT only looked at the first eight characters.

IBM mainframes, DEC minis before VMS, and most early micros were also restricted to eight characters.

The earliest email systems (dating from the early 80s and before standards SMTP etc, really came into effect) were on IBM mainframes, DEC minis and XEROX workstations.

Comment: That “earliest email systems [date] from the early 80s” is incorrect.  For example, see IETF [RFC 524](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc524), 13 June 1973, which outlines a mail protocol called MP in an attempt to standardize email methods that were already in use.